# Is it possible to provide conditional shipping options using the Stripe checkout API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's [Checkout API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout). I'd like to offer international shipping, with different shipping options whether the customer has the product shipped domestically, or internationally. Is there a way, using Checkout, to make shipping options conditional on the shipping address country the user inputs in the Checkout form?  I could of course just offer both "domestic" and "international" shipping options, but that would allow the user to select the incorrect option given the shipping country.

I know this could be done using the Payment Element product by collecting the user's shipping address ahead of time and applying my own logic to limit the shipping options before displaying the checkout form, but that would be more work, so it would be nice if this could happen all within the Checkout flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported in the [Checkout API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create).  As with the Payment Element, you would need to identify which category of shipping applied and then create the Checkout Session with the correct [`shipping_options`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_options-shipping_rate_data).

While perhaps requiring a bit more upfront work than having the Checkout API handle it all for you, you could identify the country earlier in your process and configure your application to generate "domestic" or "international" `shipping_rate_data`.

If there are certain countries where it just doesn't make sense to ship to, you can configure which countries are supported for shipping options via the [`shipping_address_collection.allowed_countries`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection-allowed_countries) parameter.